# Assigning new value based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have data frame like this one:

```
df<- data.frame(
  "Col1" = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3",
              "P3"),
  "Col2" = c("L", "L&R", "R", "V", "V&N", "N", "M", "I", "I&M",
             "I&M&G"),
  "Value" = c("20", "5", "75", "30", "7", "63", "10", "80", "2","8"))
df
```

What I want is to redefine the values based on the second column. I mean when I have  L&R in the second column I want to divide its value by 2 (from the third column which equals to 5 in this case 5) and add this results to both L and R with in the same P1 group. So, L&R=5/2 will be 2.5. This 2.5 should be added to L in P1 group to be 22.5 and to R in P1 group to be 77.5. But in a case if I have tow `&&` in the column 2 , I don't what it, so I want everything has `&&`  or  more to be ignored. The final output should look like this:

```
df.output<- data.frame(
  "Col1" = c("P1",  "P1", "P2",  "P2", "P3", "P3"),
  "Col2" = c("L",  "R", "V",  "N", "M", "I" ),
  "Value" = c("22.5",  "77.5", "33.5",  "66.5", "11",  "81"))
df.output

> df.output
  Col1 Col2 Value
1   P1    L  22.5
2   P1    R  77.5
3   P2    V  33.5
4   P2    N  66.5
5   P3    M    11
6   P3    I    81
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you explain why you ended up with `11` and `81` for `P3` group?

Comment: Hi,  because for group P3 I have 4 variables, i want the I&M value which is 2 in this case to be divided by 2 and we get 1 . i want to add 1 to both I and M in group P3 so we will get 11 for I and 81 for M. i also have I&M&G BUT i want to delete it because it  has 2 &&.

Comment: I think you made a mistake here. `I&M` value is apparently `80`, not `2`.

Comment: Yes that's true, I'm sorry ill edit it. Thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  filter(!str_count(Col2, "&") > 1) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(grepl("&", Col2), as.numeric(Value) / 2, as.numeric(Value))) %>%
  separate_rows(Col2, sep = "&") %>%
  group_by(Col1, Col2) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Col1  Col2  Value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 P1    L      22.5
2 P1    R      77.5
3 P2    N      66.5
4 P2    V      33.5
5 P3    I      42  
6 P3    M      50
```

Comment: Thank' you so much, its appreciated! Can you please clarify to me the first line of the code `filter(!str_count(Col2, "&") > 1)` ?

Comment: You're welcome that's my pleasure.

Comment: @MarwahAl-kaabi I am so sorry to answer your question late. I missed it in fact. `str_count` function counts the number of occurrence of a pattern in a string, since we need to exclude those strings that has more than 1 `&` It returns true for them. So I negated it with `!` operator and when you wrap it with `filter` function only those rows where we only have 1 `&` remains.

Comment: No worries at all, I'm really grateful for your solution, it saved me a lot of time and efforts!!! Many thanks for helping people without even knowing them!

Comment: That's my pleasure. Glad it helped. That's how it is, there are also people out there helping me without even knowing me.

Comment: Hi, its me again. Can you please help me with this code. Now I need to account for the once that have  2 of the`&`  to be accounted for but the value should be divided by 3 instead of 2.  So I need 2 lines of codes one stays as it : `mutate(Value = ifelse(grepl("&", Col2), as.numeric(Value) / 2, as.numeric(Value)))', while the second code should be somthing similar to this that deals with the `&&` and divides the value by 3 : `mutate(Value = ifelse(grepl("&&", Col2), as.numeric(Value) / 3, as.numeric(Value)))`. I tried a lot but I failed can you please help me?